# blackberry sdk installtion with netbeans

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, java-me

Any one can tell me that how to Blackberry sdk installation with netbeans for Mobile application development

i am trying to plugin but not able to do .

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this tutorial in the past](http://smhumayun.blogspot.com/2007/11/j2me-development-with-netbeans.html).  You can ignore the part about J2ME Polish.  Also, I think the **Mobility Pack** might come with new versions of Netbeans now (it didn't use to).  Or, it's possible that in the **Netbeans -> Tools -> Plugins** menu, you might need to make sure the **Java ME** plugin is installed.

He references much older SDK versions, but as long as you [download the newer JDE versions here](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/previousjdeversions/) (SDKs) from BlackBerry, the same basic instructions should work for you.

I've been using Netbeans less and less, and [the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse) more, in recent years, despite the fact that I like Netbeans better, as a general-purpose IDE.  Unfortunately, you'll find that RIM is focused on Eclipse at this point.

But, you should still be able to use Netbeans if you like.